# Spring DefaultMessageListenerContainer Consumers

Tags: weblogic, message-queue, spring-jms

I configured DefaultMessageListenerContainer to listen to the messages from WebLogic JMS. There are two instances of WebLogic instances. I noticed the consumers are always going to only one instance and it's not sharing across the instances.

Can someone advise if this is due to DefaultMessageListenerContainer config issue or issue with JMS instances?

```
@Bean
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer defaultMessageListenerContainer(MessageListenerAdapter eventListenerAdapter,
 ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
 Destination destination) {
 DefaultMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
 messageListenerContainer.setSessionTransacted(true);
 messageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(eventListenerAdapter);
 messageListenerContainer.setMessageSelector("id='1' and name='department'");
 messageListenerContainer.setDestination(destination);
 messageListenerContainer.setConcurrency("3-6");
 messageListenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
 return messageListenerContainer;
}


@Bean(name = "destination")
public JndiObjectFactoryBean destination(JndiTemplate jndiTemplate) {
 JndiObjectFactoryBean queueJndi = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
 queueJndi.setJndiTemplate(jndiTemplate);
 queueJndi.setJndiName("DEPT_QUEUE");
 return queueJndi;
}

@Bean(name = "connectionFactory")
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
 return (ConnectionFactory) jmsConnectionFactory().getObject();
}

@Bean(name = "eventListenerAdapter")
public MessageListenerAdapter eventListenerAdapter() {
 MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter = new MessageListenerAdapter(processEventsListener);
 messageListenerAdapter.setDefaultListenerMethod("processEvents");
 messageListenerAdapter.setMessageConverter(null);
 return messageListenerAdapter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved by unchecking load balance "Server Affinity Enabled" property